# I want to know what is that form_open array in Codeigniter 3.0.6

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've continue to develop the phase 2 project. In the phase 1 codes, i found these form_open. I understand the other codes, but i didn't know the array('id' => 'edit'). Please explain me how it's work.

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url().'admin_user_edit/index/',array('id' => 'edit'));?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`form_open()` is codeigniter's form `helper` function that creates an opening form tag with a base URL built from your config preferences. It will optionally let you add form attributes and hidden input fields, and will always add the accept-charset attribute based on the charset value in your config file.

Here’s a simple example:

```
echo form_open('email/send');
```

The above example would create a form that points to your base URL plus the “email/send” URI segments, like this:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http://example.com/index.php/email/send">
```

For more see docs [Codeigniter Form Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
array('id' => 'edit')
```

is for form tag attribute.
You can add form tag attribute in array.

its affect like this

```
<form action="project/admin_user_edit/index" id="edit">
```

you can pass many attribute in array like this

```
array('id' => 'edit','class' => 'classname')
```

its affect like this

```
<form action="project/admin_user_edit/index" id="edit" class="classname">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form_open(base_url().'admin_user_edit/index/',array('id' => 'edit'));
```

is equivalent to `html`  tag:

```
<form id="edit" action="project/admin_user_edit/index">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

form_open contains parameter
The first parameter is your target or action which redirects you to the function or page.
Second parameter is used as array in which you pass attributes and their value just like class, id or others

```
<form action="your_action/send" class="email" id="myform">
```

or you can write like this

```
$attributes = array('class' => 'email', 'id' => 'myform');
echo form_open('your_action/send', $attributes);
```

you can inspect your code on web browser